# Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver 2.39.0 + Firefox 26.0.
My Firefox driver instantiate and I am successfully able to log in into my application.
After that my script is not able to perform any further actions. But the same is working fine on WebDriver 2.39.0 + IE 9.

Please suggest!

Error appears as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
```

Comment: it is problem with webdriver version use  WebDriver 2.38.0 then try!

Comment: Please try using firefox version 24

Comment: Three year old question, with no code, how isn't this closed already?

Answer (score 0):

can you use below code to initialize the firefox browser and give it a try:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Firefox. Just make sure that the version of WebDriver you have is compatible with the version of Firefox you have by going to the [Selenium site](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the configurations that works..
Please try

1) upgrading from Selenium 2.41.0 to 2.44.0 worked for me.
Using Firefox v33.1.1

2) Install Selenium 2.45 + FF 36.0.4 .the issue will be resolved

3) it works with selenuim 2.43 and firefox 32.0.3

4) selenium-java (2.45.0) with FF 34.0 works!

Answer (score 0):

As per the log, browser is not interacting.Try to update your FF and selenium server as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did have this error 2 days ago. The Firefox version is too new for the web-driver and is not compatible with each other, try installing an older version of Firefox. (I use Firefox version 36.0.1 with Selenium 2.48.2 and works perfect).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide specific version of Firefox, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver version and Firefox version should be in sync. Webdriver version is not compatible with latest version of Firefox. This is most common issue, try to install older version of Firefox. With new selenium 3.0 we won't see this issue. We use geckodriver. Hope this information helps.